# Копирование в Excel

Tags: javascript, excel

Как с помощью javascripta сделать так, чтобы массив текста копировался только в 1 ячейку экселя?

Т.е.: убрать переводы строк при выделении и копировании

Comment: Зачем для этого что-то убирать? Тупо `Range("address").Value=long_text`

Comment: Можно более подробный пример.

Comment: А разве в экселе не VBA? Или уже js ?